# Affine neighbourhood containing two given points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

> Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety and two distinct points $P,Q\in X$. Prove there is an affine open subset $\mathcal{U}\subset X$ containing both $P$ and $Q$.

Assuming $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ is an affine variety, we can take any linear form $L$ with $L(P)=L(Q)=0$. Therefore $P,Q\notin V(L+1)$, so that $P,Q\in X\setminus V(L+1)$, which is an affine open subset of $X$.

I'm trying to argue that we can assume $X$ is affine without loss of generality, but I don't know if this is possible. If not, how could I solve this?

Comment: What is the definition of quasi-affine?

Comment: I meant quasi-projective (just corrected it), which is an open subset of some projective variety $V\subset\mathbb{P}^n$

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do : if $X$ is already affine, you are done right ? I mean, no need to take a linear form $L$ such that ..., just take $\mathcal{U}=X$.

Comment: @Roland, you're right, assuming $X$ affine was just silly! Anyway, following your suggestion, you mean $P,Q\in \mathbb{P}^n\setminus V(L)$, right? But then is it true that $X\cap (\mathbb{P}^n\setminus V(L))$ is affine?

Comment: No this is not true unfortunately, that is why I removed my comment a few second after posting it. I realized that you only have a quasi-affine subset.

Comment: I think you can still make it works : so first choose an hyperplane $H$ such that $P,Q\not\in H$, you then have $P,Q\in X\setminus H$ which is quasi-affine. So we can assume $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ quasi-affine. Take $\overline{X}$ its closure and $Z=\overline{X}\setminus X$. It is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$, so given by $V(I)$. Choose generators $f_1,...,f_k$ of $I$. Now $V(I)\subset V(a_1f_1+...+a_kf_k)$ for any $a_1,...,a_k$. The purpose is to find some $k$-uplet $(a_1,..,a_k)$ such that $P,Q\not\in V(a_1f_1+...+a_kf_k)$. This should be possible.

Comment: @Roland, can we guarantee that $a_1f_1+...+a_kf_k$ is irreducible? That should be necessary for $\overline{X}\setminus V(a_1f_1+...+a_kf_k)$ to be affine, right?

Comment: No it is not necessary. For any $f$, $D_f=\overline{X}\setminus V(f)$ is affine.